# Airflow: missing keyword argument 'bash_command'`

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Requirement: To create a CustomOperator to run RScript extending BashOperator

Issue: It threw an Airflow exception as missing keyword argument 'bash_command'`

Code:

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults

class ROpertor(BashOperator):
    """
    Execute an R script.

    :param script_path: The local path to the R script.
    :type script_path: str
    :param args: List of arguments to pass to the R script.
    :type args: list
    :param r_cmd: The command to use to invoke R. The default is
        ``"Rscript"``, which should work in most cases.
    :type r_cmd: str
    """

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
        self,
        script_path,
        arg=None,
        r_cmd="Rscript",
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.script_path = script_path
        self.arg = arg or []
        self.r_cmd = r_cmd

    def execute(self, context):
        command = f"{self.r_cmd} {self.script_path}"
        if self.arg:
            command += " " + " ".join(self.arg)
        return_code = self.execute_command(command, context)
        if return_code:
            raise AirflowException("Command failed")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inheriting from `BashOperator`. The parameter `bash_command` is mandatory for `BashOperator`.

You can have `r_command` as part of your interface in `ROpertor` and under the hood use `bash_command`.

Comment: Thanks, I. missed out the bash_command